# url_for() to call static files in ajax

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm implementing autocomplete with Flask and JavaScript, and I'm trying to put the JavaScript in a different file. My folder structure is like:

```
- Project
    - static
    |   -js
    |      autocomplete.js
    - templates
    |   index.html  
    main.py
```

If I add the script in `index.html`:

```html
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
    }).done(function (data) {
         $('#inputBox').autocomplete({
             source: data,
             minLength: 1
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine, but when I put the code into `/static/js/autocomplete.js` and add `<script src="../static/js/autocomplete.js"></script>` in `index.html`,
I get a 404:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Oct/2017 07:54:10] "GET /%7B%7B%20url_for(%22static%22,%22autocomplete%22)%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So how I should write the path in `url_for()`?

Comment: The python code has a line like: @app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET']).  I'm not calling the js from python, but oppositely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find what you need here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files

Basically you just need a "static" folder at the root of your package, and then you can use url_for('static', filename='js/autocomplete.js') or directly link to your files with http://example.com/static/js/autocomplete.js

Comment: Tnx for the answer, but your example is calling js in python code. I want to call python method in js.

Comment: You cannot call python methods within javascript. If you want to call a url from flask, do you need to create a route for this url and call that route.

Comment: Sorry, for some misunderstanding. If I put the above javascript in my index.html with <script> ..... </script> then it works perfectly. But if I put the script in individual file in /static/js/autocomplete.js and in index.html I use <script src="/static/js/autocomplete.js"></script> it returns 404. can not find path autocomplete ...

Comment: I made mistake, sorry. After check the document I was able to add include to reach the url. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='js/autocomplete') }}
```